# TimeScaleData in project using C#

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project

When i read resource name has start 4/3/2017 and finish 4/7/2017,during work he
off in 4/6/2017 and return in 4/7/2017.So, i try to use timescaledata in other show actual work in 3,4,5,7 it run only 3,4,5 and skip 7.So, how to get value all 3,4,5 and 7

**Update**

```
  private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application();
        app.FileOpenEx(Path, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadWrite, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project pj = app.ActiveProject;
            foreach (Task taskmbc in pj.Tasks)
            {
                foreach(Resource re in taskmbc.Resources)
                {
                    DateTime date = taskmbc.Start;
                    string def = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    foreach (Assignment assign in taskmbc.Assignments)
                    {

                        var tsvs = assign.TimeScaleData(dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker2.Value, MSProject.PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledWork, MSProject.PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleDays);
                      foreach (TimeScaleValue tsv in tsvs)
                            { 
                          try
                        {


                                MessageBox.Show(assign.TaskName + "Start" + tsv.StartDate + (tsv.Value) / 60 + assign.ResourceName + tsv.EndDate);
                            }

                        catch { }
                          }
                        }
                    }
            }
            }
```

Comment: 1) Just loop through the assignments for each task (skip looping through the resources). 2) Try adding 1 day to your `dateTimePicker2.Value`.

Comment: @RachelHettinger  I did but it still skip 7.

Comment: It's not skipping 4/7, an exception is raised on 4/6 because `tsv.Value` is Null when there is no work.