# VSTO Microsoft Project & Visual Studio C#: How do I read Actual Hours and Work (Hours) by task by resource by day date?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, ms-project

Visual Studio, C# VSTO to MS Project Desktop

I am '*simply*' trying to extract Actual and Work Hours data per day for each Task and Resource?
There does not appear to be many examples on line for VS VSTO MS-Project so I am hoping this question will help me and others too.

Example:

10/2/2021, Tell Jokes, Rod Gilbert, 4, 4

10/2/2021, Tell Jokes, Michael McIntyre, 2, 4

Comment: See [TimeScaleData in Project using .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029833/timescaledata-in-project-using-net) for an example of how to loop through task assignments to get the work per day. Yes, there are not many VSTO examples and fewer still in C#, but here's one: [TimeScaleData in project using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46598629/timescaledata-in-project-using-c-sharp).

Comment: Hi @RachelHettinger, thank you for your reply and suggested article. Stew

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use Assignments in C# which I THINK is different in VBA.

```
 var tsvs = ass.TimeScaleData(pj.ProjectStart,
              pj.ProjectFinish,
              MSProject.PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledWork,
              MSProject.PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleDays, 1);
```

Comment: The [TimeScaleData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignment.timescaledata) method of the Assignment object is used for this purpose regardless of whether you use C#, vb.net, or VBA.